# Variable assignment in lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, variable-assignment, final

I have the following fragment of code:

```
    SomeClass someClass;
    switch (type) {
        case FIRST:
            someClass = new SomeClass();
            break;
        case SECOND:
            OptionalLong optional = findSomeOptional();
            optional.ifPresent(value -> someClass = new SomeClass(value));
    }
```

And I'm trying to assign new object to **someClass** reference in lambda expresion but then I've got error message: *"variable used in lambda should be effectively final"*.

When I add **final** to declaration of someClass I got another error *"cannot assign value to final variable"*

So how can I smartly deal with such assigment in lamdas?

Comment: Why do you want to use a lambda? Why not just `someClass = optional.isPresent() ? new SomeClass(value) : null;`?

Comment: Nothing specific. It just seems for me as an elegant way to use ifPresent and lambda when I operate on Optional values..

Comment: Not really, when you want to modify local variables. That's just not something lambdas support. When a feature doesn't fit, I'd use something else.

Comment: Thanks, good lesson for me - do not try to use lamdas in every possible place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is you cannot assign local variables from upper levels in lambda expressions.

Either, you turn your variable into an instance member, or use an simple if statement:

```
SomeClass someClass;
switch (type) {
  case FIRST:
    someClass = new SomeClass();
  break;
  case SECOND:
    OptionalLong optional = findSomeOptional();
    if(optional.isPresent()) {
      someClass = new SomeClass(optional.getAsLong());
    }
}
```

The last option would be to use an `AtomicReference`.

Comment: Correction: you cannot assign to _uplevel_ locals in a lambda.  Lambdas can declare their own locals and mutate them.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use an `OptionalLong`, or can you use an `Optional<Long>`?

An appropriate idiom for what you want to do is `someClass = optional.map(SomeClass::new).orElse(someClass)`. However, `OptionalLong` doesn't have a `map(LongFunction)` method, for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

[AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) can be declared as final and used to hold a reference.